# Индекс за пределами диапазона. Индекс должен быть положительным числом, а его размер не должен превышать размер коллекции. Имя параметра: index

Tags: datagridview, диаграммы, listbox

Моя идея заключается в следующем получаю запрос выводить либо listBox1, либо dataGridView1 и потом отображать эти значения в chart1. Но получаю эту ошибку. Пробовал listBox1, через reader на прямую, а так же dataGridView1, в одном запросе из полученных данных вставлял проценты вычисления и вставлял в на прямую chart1 и все равно одна и та же ошибка. Причем в listBox1 и dataGridView1 данные заполняются.

```
chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = (ds.Tables[0].Columns[0]).ToString();  - ошибка
chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = (ds.Tables[0].Columns[1]).ToString();
```

Полная ошибка

```
Error: System.ArgumentOutRangeException: Индекс за пределами диапазона. Индекс должен быть положительным числом, а его размер не должен превышать размер коллекции. 

Имя параметра: index в
System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentutRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)

в System.Collection.Generic.List1.get_Item(Int32 index)
в System.Collection.ObjectModel.Collection 1.get_Item(Int32 index)
в Turagenstvo.Form9.button1_Click(Oblect sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: Дополнительная информация к размышлению, которую я не могу понять
Пробовал listBox1, через reader на прямую, а так же dataGridView1, в одном запросе из полученных данных вставлял проценты вычисления и все равно одна и та же ошибка. Причем в listBox1 и dataGridView1 данные заполняются.

Comment: Проверяли количество серий в chart1, количество таблиц в ds, и количество колонок в ds.Tables[0] ?